# lof alphabetically sorted

Tags: floats

Writing a special dictionary, I have inserted some hundred figures.
The normal list of figures does not make much sense in this case as nowbody is really interested in the order of occurrence but in the contents -> what I am looking for is a list of figures alphabetically sorted according to the captions.

Any idea how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: In this sense, it would be better, to create a `listofsomething` of your own, using the possibilities of `caption` and `tocloft` packages. However, the sorting might have to be transferred to an external program.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you might consider treating this as an index.  `imakeidx` has some very nice capabilities.  if you can accept having the list placed at the end of the document, you can take advantage of the fact that only one latex pass would be needed to accomplish the compilation and sorting; if the list must be at the beginning, then the `[original]` option would be needed, and the sorting step would be done separately.  `imakeidx` indexes are normally two columns; i haven't researched what would be necessary to make them single column and reformat the contents to look like a toc.

Answer (score 1):

Here my workaround I tried successfully:

under linux command sequence:

1. latex latexfilename.tex
2. sort -k4 latexfilename.lof > a.lof; mv a.lof latexfilename.lof
3. latex latexfilename.tex

   --> now uses the externally sorted lof file
   --> list of figure looks like as wanted :-)

drawback: running latex now again lists figures in order of occurrence again, therefore the sorting has to be done each time before running latex

Comment: You could put the sort command in a shell script and execute it at the beginning of your document using `\write18`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252957/how-to-execute-shell-script-from-latex. Other than that you can write a makefile to sort the file for you, as suggested in the linked answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146435/how-do-i-sort-a-file-in-place-using-bash-shell for avoiding the temporary file. But it's unclear to me what `-k4` is supposed to do.